# How to repeat a task every X ms on STM32F303VCT6 (C++) using timers/interrupts?

Tags: stm32, c++, keil

My aim is to do the following:
1- Repeat a task every 250ms and when the button is pressed the task is repeated every 500ms, and if the button is pressed again go back to every 250ms.
2- I plan on using Keil MDK Arm not STM32Cube IDE.
3- I plan on using interrupts not polling.

This is a code snippet from my work:

```
// indicates when input is received
volatile bool IP_flag = false;

 // perform an example run of the processing and then run a loop to light LEDs
 // and respond to the button presses
 int main(void)
 {
  // initialize the GPIO for the input/output of ports and set up interrupts
  gpio_setup();

 // timer interrupt frequency in 10ths of a microsecond (do not exceed 0xFFFFFF)
 SysTick_Config(1000000);


// START - EXAMPLE OF OPERATIONS THAT NEED TO BE PERFORMED BETWEEN
// TIMER INTERRUPTS

  // define objects for processing the database values and storing
 // the results of the calculations
   Process P(*Database);
   Results R;

   // perform processing and store the results
uint32_t total = P.ProcessAll();
for(uint8_t i=0;i<DATABASE_ROWS; i++) {
    total = P.ProcessRow();
  R.StoreResult(total);
P.NextRow();
}
```

Process is class that has functions to carry out some calculations and store them inside an array in the Results class.

I know the SysTick_Handler(void) function also is related to the Systick_Config. Like this is defined outside int main():

```
 void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
   {
  if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_0) { // check the user button has generated the 
    interrupt
     GPIOE->ODR = GPIOE->ODR ^ (uint16_t) LED10;  // toggle red LED at top of board
     IP_flag = true;
     }
      }
   void SysTick_Handler(void)
     {
      GPIOE->ODR = GPIOE->ODR ^ (uint16_t) LED3;  // toggle red LED at bottom of 
     board
       }
```

This blinks the LED3 related to SysTick_Config.

Main questions:
1- How to repeat a task(ProcessRow() function) every 250ms, when the button is pressed change the repetition to say 500ms? If the CPU clock is 72Mhz how do I calculate what to put inside SysTick_Config?

2- Once the interrupt frequency is figured out, do I place the ProcessRow() function inside the SysTick_Handler to make it repeat every 250ms?

Comment: Ask your instructor. But before you do, format your code so that it is readable.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The code is formatted fine. Do you want to see the whole code? Also, I don't understand the part about instructor, if I could simply ask someone I would not post it on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The 'general' solution would be to use a RTOS like FreeRTOS. This gives you an expandable base to work from.

Keil have their own RTOS whose name escapes me at the moment.

But, if you want to 'roll your own' then there are many, many ways of solving the problem. My suggestion would be to setup the systick interrupt for a time period of ,say, 10ms. The actual value is not super critical, but you want a value that is 'useful' - not too fast but fast enough. At 10ms, that's 100 ticks per second.

Don't use external interrupts for switches - bad juju. Only do this if you want to wake the cpu from sleep. Once woken, poll the switch input in the systick isr and debounce/filter it.

For your task timing, keep a count variable that is decremented in the systick isr. When it gets to 0, then it's time to run your task. Set a flag and poll this flag in the main loop.

you can run your task code in the systick isr, but that is not extensible. What happens when you want to add tasks? It becomes unmanageable. You generally want to keep your isr code lean 'n' mean. Once you have multiple interrupt sources, they will compete for attention. Keeping your isrs lean means very little time is spent in a given isr so others can get fast response.

Once you get past a couple of tasks, things can get tricky. Probably time for an RTOS. Just about any embedded systems job ad will want RTOS experience, so now is probably the best time to get some. There's a little bit of a learning curve, but things haven't changed much in the last 50 years of RTOS, so there's plenty of info out there.